# How do I get the new files added to a repo with the GitHub API?

Tags: api, github

Say I have a GitHub repo with lots of files. Somebody adds a new file or changes an old one with a commit. How do I get a list of just the files that were changed on the last commit?

Comment: Super easy? Impossible?